# Sending Email via ActionMailer::Base using SMTP, but sender should be another email-adress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sender

i'm searching for a way to send emails with ruby on rails via actionMailer. The difficulty is, that i am sending the emails via gmail smtp. But i have to send them from different email-adresses (the customers have to be able to setup there own email adress, but i dont want to save the credentials).
Any Idea?

Thanks"!

Answer (score 0):

you have to setup a mail server to send your mails for you and you just send the mail with the headers saying that it is from the person's email address. there are many mail servers, sendmail being one of the standards for a VPS. if you pick a service like heroku, they have mailing as an addon: http://addons.heroku.com/sendgrid